# php ffmpeg 3gp watermark not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am completely new to `php ffmpeg`. I tried to watermark a 3gp video in my shared ffmpeg installed server. But it doesn't output anything other than `LOADED` as stated in the code. The ouput is also not creating. Can anyone please solve the problem?

```
<?php
if(extension_loaded('ffmpeg')){
echo 'LOADED';
$c = 'ffmpeg –i video.3gp -vf "movie=watermark.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]" outputvideo.3gp';
exec($c);
}
?>
```

When i used `phpinfo()` what i get about `ffmpeg` is

```
ffmpeg
ffmpeg-php version 0.6.0-svn
ffmpeg-php built on May 10 2013 11:50:44
ffmpeg-php gd support enabled
ffmpeg libavcodec version Lavc52.122.0
ffmpeg libavformat version Lavf52.110.0
ffmpeg swscaler version SwS0.14.1
ffmpeg.allow_persistent 0 0
ffmpeg.show_warnings 0 0
```

Comment: maybe you should try to run to command in shell, or see the output using `exec($c, $output)` then echo the `$output`

Comment: I tried and got `Array()` when i used `print_r($out)`

Comment: I just changed `exec($c,$out)` with `shell_exec($c,$out)` and `var_dump($out)`. The result was `NULL`

Comment: if you have access to shell, try to run the command in bash shell

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ffmpeg -i amitabh-i\ can\ talk\ english.flv  -s qcif amitabh.3gp
```